# npm ERR! code CERT_HAS_EXPIRED - Angular 13

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, npm, npm-install

I have installed angular and it shows me the version and everything. But when I try to run command **npm start** it gives me error. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything but this issue 't go away. I tried to run **npm install** and I got this error. (screenshots attached)

[ng --version output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRLVa.png)

[npm start output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg261.png)

[npm install output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sghOZ.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use a custom package registry which requires an active certificate.

It is not project or Angular related, it's npm and registry related.

Your options are:

1. Renew your certificate
2. Use a different or default registry
3. Make it so that your registry no longer requires a certificate.

Check [`npm config list`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config) to see your current settings

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because your npm certificate is outdated.

Locate your .npmrc file under C:\Users\userName

And remove all data

Update the file with the following line

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED," indicates that the SSL certificate used by the npm registry has expired. This can happen for various reasons, such as outdated npm or network issues.

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of npm. You can update npm by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

   npm install -g npm@latest
2. Clear the npm cache by running:

   npm cache clean -f
3. You can switch to a different npm registry. In your case, it seems you are using the Taobao registry. You can switch back to the default registry by running:

   npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/